# How do I escape double quotes in oracle query?

Tags: php, oracle, escaping

I have some text fields in the oracle table, which have double quotes. How to escape them in a select query, so that I can use it in PHP?

Comment: Is it the field *names* that have quotes, or the field *values*?

Comment: You do **not** need to escape the selected text in your **query**. Just select it like any other field and do your business **within** PHP. e.g. str_replace('"', '&quot;', $field); or something similar. 
Usually, you need to escape your text before you **insert** it into a database table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do a

```
SELECT REPLACE(your_column, '"', '\"') AS your_escaped_column
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Bad response. If the table contaíns 100000000 rows, this search in all rows and replace the value.

Comment: @Fernando. I'm afraid I don't fully understand your comment. I did not expect this query to be used to return all 100,000,000 rows but to be filtered by _another_ column instead. Escaping the quotes might not be necessary in this form (see other comments/answers), but I do not expect it to be slower in the query than in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Odds are, if you are trying to do this you are dealing with a SQL Injection vulnerability. Please Google this and think about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: "\""

Answer (score 0):

Well... you'd select them out just like you would any other field.  It's when you are putting things *in* to the database where you need to escape them.

That has different mechanisms depending on what database abstraction layer or driver you're using.

For drivers, I recommend PDO.  That way, it doesn't matter which database you're using, escaping a field for input is always going to be something like this:

```
// Assuming that $dbh is a valid PDO object, like this one:
// $dbh = new PDO('oci:dbname=//hostname:1521/scott', 'scott', 'tiger');
// That's 'oci:dbname=//hostname:port-number/database', username, password

$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = ':myName'";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':myName' => "Ed O'Neil"));
```